# Как изменить интервал в mathplotlib не меняя рисунок?

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется программа с выводом рисунка в matplolib, однако цифры интервала не те что мне хотелось, получается у меня интервал идет от мат ожидания до стандартного отклонения, что похоже на сюр. Хотелось бы чтобы туда можно было вписывать значения например в метрах. Почитал есть plt.xlim () и plt.ylim (), однако тогда рисунок уходит за эти пределы.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from tkinter import *

def makeData():
    x = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 200)  
    y = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 200)
    r = .1  # радиус маски
    x0, y0 = 2.7, 2.8 # центр маски
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y) 
    z = np.random.normal(xgrid, ygrid)
    r = .1  # радиус маски
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    mask = (X - x0) ** 2 + (Y - y0) ** 2 < r ** 2
    return xgrid, ygrid, z, X, Y, mask

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y, z, X, Y, mask = makeData()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_blue', ['b', 'g', 'y', 'r'], 256)
    axes.plot_surface(x, y, z *(1 + mask * 0.75), color='#11aa55', cmap=cmap)
    axes.set_xlabel('Размер помещения в метрах')
    axes.set_ylabel('Размер помещения в метрах')
    axes.set_zlabel('Температура')
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О каком интервале вообще речь? А так то у вас `z = np.random.normal(xgrid, ygrid)`, тут действительно генерируется нормальное распределение, которое вас почему-то удивляет.

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: Так этот интервал у вас задан `x = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 200); y = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 200)`, вот от `2.5` до `3` и получается и по `x` и по `y`, а вы что ожидали?

Comment: Согласен с вами, а нельзя его изменить не меняя рисунок? Я планировал размер помещения смоделировать

Comment: Ну поставьте тогда в `linspace` какие хотите числа (ну, кроме третьего числа - это число точек). Или вам нужно, чтобы рисунок был на тех же координатах, а координатные оси показывались в другом диапазоне? В этом случае используйте `xlim`, `ylim`, да.

Comment: если указываю xlim, ylim например от 0 до 10 метров, то рисунок не правильно отображается

Comment: если бы можно сделать чтобы нормальное распределение менялось от размеров xlim, ylim, вот наверно тогда бы получилось

Comment: Я всё-равно не понимаю, что вы хотите. Вы параметры `linspace` пробовали менять, это не то, что вам нужно? Пробовали `0, 10, 200` там поставить? Только учтите, что для маски тоже формулу нужно скорректировать будет.

Comment: да пробовал, выложил изображение 3, маску удалил, чтобы проще было, тогда получился другой график

Comment: Чем вам конкретно последний график не нравится? Я всё ещё не понимаю, что вы хотите.

Comment: Хочу сделать нормальное распределение температуры помещения, цвета сверху вниз, красный, желтый, зеленый, синий, где маска это человек красным цветом, то есть высокой температуры

Comment: и вроде первый график более менее похож, однако сам куб в котором находится график хотел сделать подобием помещения, где пользователь бы вводил метраж своего

Comment: Добавьте `colorbar` к графику, может чуть понятнее что-то станет. И вообще почитайте вот ещё, может найдёте что-то полезное ещё https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-three-dimensional-data-heatmaps-contours-and-3d-plots-with-python-bd718d1b42b4